# TFS2010 - Copy work item value only when item is created

Tags: tfs

We're using TFS2010 for our team project.

When an new workitem is created we want to copy the value from System.CreatedBy to another field... but we should be able to change this value. Copying the value isn't the problem but every time the workitem is saved it copy's the value again.

Is there any way to copy the value only when the workitem is created and not when it's saved?

Comment: If you use Copy rule of field definition, then you'll see the value available after saving the work item. When a user changes or creates a work item, the COPY rule fills in a field value regardless of any value that is already in the field.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking for is to be able to copy the value of `Created By` to another field, but only on creation of the work item, never another time.

If so, the answer is yes, but you cannot write the rules in the `FIELD` definition; you have to write the rules in the `WORKFLOW`, specifically, in the transition from "" to New (or whatever your first state is).

Something like this.

```
<TRANSITIONS>
    <TRANSITION from="" to="New">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="New" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Your.Field">
          <COPY from="currentuser" />
          <REQUIRED />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
</TRANSITIONS>
```